# Selecting the records with maximum date value

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

```
String sql1="SELECT MAX(date),epf_rte_emp,epf_rte_com,etf_rte FROM Fixed_Rates1";
```

I'm using this query to select the record with the maximum date value, but it gives the latest updated record. I want the record with the maximum date.This query gives the record with maximum date in the SQLiteManager, but doesn't gives the required output in netbeans. Could someone please help me in this?

Comment: Is "date" a column in the table?

Comment: yes "date" column is in the table..

Comment: My suggestion was going to be to put "date" in double quotes, so it would know it was meant as a column name and not the `date` keyword, but if the other suggestion works, may as well use that.

Comment: This construct works in SQLite 3.7.11 or later. Apparently, the SQLite driver used by Netbeans is several years out of date.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one record, then something like this shoudl work:

```
select fr.*
from fixed_rates1 fr
order by date desc
limit 1;
```

Note:  I am guessing you are using MySQL, because your query would fail in most other databases.  The method for limiting results depends on the database.

If you want all rows with the maximum date:

```
select fr.*
from fixed_rates1 fr
where fr.date = (select max(fr2.date) from fixed_rates1 fr2);
```

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff.. . Thanks a lot 